# Test Kerberos Authentication without throwing exception

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, kerberos

I'm using an HDFS keytab to perform certain superuser operations on an API call. The keytabs change roughly every 6 months, sometimes more frequently if a breach occurs. Whenever this happens, my application needs to fetch the latest keytabs from a remote host over SSH.

For performance reasons, on each API call, I would like to determine if the existing keytab is still valid and current. (If not, there's no need to fetch it.) One way to do is to try using the keytab, and if an exception is thrown, fetch the new keytab. However, I don't like this approach because I understand that [using exception handling to control flow is an anti-pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why).

Ideally, I would query some sort of API to check the current keytab's validity, and only fetch the latest keytab if necessary. Do the `UserGroupInformation` Java APIs provide a way to do this?

Comment: I don't believe this is an anti pattern in this situation (every N months). The call to `UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI` will throw an Exception if your keytab is invalid. I don’t see any other method available to check keytab validity.

Comment: Ideally, the **next** password should be known a few hours in advance, before it is enforced. That way it could be appended to the existing _keytab_, with a higher `kvno`. The kerberos clients are expected to get the highest `kvno` and try to connect, and on error, try again with the previous `kvno`... hence resolving any issue with password updates (incl. issues with replication delays between master and slave KDCs).